# Which one is right?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

A single string columned table which is also the PK OR create an integer auto increment column as its PK and then set the string column as an UNIQUE field?

Comment: Depends how long the string field is and whether its unchnaging, and what it's used for...

Comment: How can we tell you what is "right" when we don't even know what you are trying to do? What do you hope to achieve by adding another column?

Comment: Mitch, it would be a 250 characters long field, based on the answers I'm realizing what would be the cost of updating a string PK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on what you want to achieve.

If you want a stable database schema which you can change later, always add ID columns and use those as primary keys.

If maintenance is not necessary or not wanted, you can use the strings as keys and waste countless hours later when one of those "immutable" keys must be changed to update it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely #2. A PK column should never contain business data.

Comment: something like a state might be an exception from this advice

Comment: @Mitch: not really. postcodes change. And natural keys like that have the ugly tendency to not be as constant/unique as one hopes. And few things are worse than primary keys that change or primary keys that are not unique. My experience is that **almost all** "natural keys" turn out to be really bad key candidates.

Comment: Disagree with your second statement. It can be business data, if it doesn't decrease performance

Comment: @damluar - of course it can be anything you want :) However I would argue it's bad design to use business data as a PK, if not for purely aesthetic reasons, then for the reason that business data might always be subject to change, even if not considered in the first design phases.

Comment: @matk, that's no justiification for the silly statement that a key shouldn't contain business data. Take the example given here. If the business data has to change then at least one of the keys will have to change. Adding another key doesn't necessarily make such a change easier or more "correct" - it may make it harder.

Comment: @dportas - using a non-business data auto increment column as PK would not be adding another key, it would be THE key. Aaron already gave a good example above why having business data as the PK might be problematic: There's no guarantee that your data will always be unique, and if turns out it isn't, you're in maintenance hell. So, even though one might not call that approach "correct", I would call it the favored design approach based on my own experience.

Comment: @matk, Seems like you didn't notice the last two words of the OP's original question. He's suggesting a table with BOTH keys, not just one. Are you really suggesting that he shouldn't enforce the business key and should allow duplicates instead?!!

Comment: @dportas - we're probably just using different terms here. I usually don't call a unique index a "key". If you do, that's fine; in that case you would be right and the table would have two "keys". Obviously I'm not suggesting that duplicates should be allowed; after all, in my answer I advocated using the OP's 2nd suggestion, which included a UNIQUE constraint. What I am saying though is that IF requirements change and duplicate values are allowed, THEN it is easier to remove the UNIQUE constraint rather then updating the PK, and all related tables along with it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of the string column. However, I believe the second one would be much better, when you would run queries against the table.

Comment: I agree. Joins against int columns tend to perform better (a nice analysis can be found [here](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/02/15/are-int-joins-faster-than-string-joins-2/).